# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Getting this error in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I am using WSL2. My docker desktop integrated with WSL, I mean integrated with Ubuntu 20.04. When docker running in my windows machine perfectly but it is showing this error on linux side. Can't understand what to do.
[image]